# Character comes out as a black square

Tags: symbols, characters

I am using Overleaf and I inserted this character 'ŋ' in the text of my document. There is no error and all the other characters as œ and ø work fine, but only this one when compiled is showed as a black square. I also tried the `\ng` command, but it also comes out as a black square. Can I do anything to change this? I am using `mathptmx` font and T1 as `fontenc`. (Hopefully without changing the font becuase it's one of the requirements for my work.)

Comment: use `\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}` instead of mathptmx.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I believe `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` is safer. `newtxmath` checks if you are using `newtxtext` and acts accordingly.

Comment: If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, I’d recommend `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` and `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}`. If using PDFLaTeX, the previous comments are great advice.

Comment: Another solution may be `\usepackage{tipa}` and then input the character as `\textipa{N}`.